# Radius of inscribed circle

Tags: geometry

Is there a general formula pertaining radii of inscribed circles, regardless of whether the figures they're inscribed to are curvilined or not, and ofc, under the premise a circle is inscribable within them (hence, rectangular shapes are excluded)?

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways you can approach this type of question is by using the formula: $Area = p \cdot r \implies r = \frac{Area}{p}$, where $p$ is semiperimeter (half of the perimeter) of $n$-gon.

Comment: I knew that formula, but I was asking about a wider range of cases, such as, as mentioned, curved figures.